# What is the difference between "niedrig" and "gering"

Tags: meaning

For me both has same meaning but there should be difference which I couldn't figure out yet. Could you help?

duden dictionary:

https://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/niedrig%20%5Bgering%5D

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Hättest Du mal die Dudeneinträge gelesen: niedrig: 1a. von geringer Höhe. gering: 2. einer niedrigen sozialen Schicht angehörend.

Comment: Niedrig ist tatsächlich *von geringer **Hohe***, und nicht **gering**, usw. *Kurz* ist auch *von geringer **Länge***, nehme ich an. Und trotzdem ist *kurz* != *gering*.

Answer (score 8):

*Niedrig* means *low* (as opposite to *hoch* = *high*) and
 
*gering* means *minor* or *small* (as opposite to *groß* = *big*).

In some contexts, the differences are blurred, e.g.

> Chances are low --> Die Chancen sind gering

But that is more an idiomatic difference than a bad translation. One also says

> Die Chancen sind groß

and not so often

> Die Chancen sind hoch

for

> The chances are high

Comment: I don't think you really answer the question. In addition, I don't think there is a proper answer. One can say *von niedriger Höhe* or *von geringer Höhe*, I would never say *Die Chancen sind groß*, although it's not false.

Comment: @RoyPJ "One can say von niedriger Höhe or von geringer Höhe" This wrong. It's either "niedrig" or "von geringer Höhe". Don't mix it.

Comment: @Aloso: indeed. And to RoyPJ: Oh yes, there is a difference, in German as well as in English. Of course you can say *von niedriger Höhe*, like I could say *my hovercraft is full of eels*, but both would be wrong. <g>

Answer (score 6):

*Niedrig* is related to height, whereas *gering* is more generally related to an amount.

Which of the two words fits better depends if the usage concerns something physical, or if the words are used in a figurative sense.

An examples for a physical usage is:

> Die Mauer ist *niedrig*.  (kleine Höhe)

It is possible to say

> Das Brett hat eine *geringe* Länge. (= es ist kurz)

In a figurative sense, the differences are less:

> Eine Person von *niedrigem* IQ.  Eine Person von *geringem* IQ.
>
> Sie hatte nur ein *niedriges* Einkommen. Sie hatte nur ein *geringes* Einkommen.

Both sentences are more or less equivalent.

Comment: "Niedrig" is not only related to height, but also to **numbers**. Since the IQ is a number, you should only say "von niedrigem IQ". However, you can say "von geringer Intelligenz".

Comment: "She had a low income" and "she had a small income" are different in English too.

Comment: @Aloso: You are right that "niedrig" is also related to numbers. However I disagree with your conclusion that with numbers, only "niedrig" should be used.