# Difference between "wenig " , "niedrig " , "kaum " , "gering" , " ein bisschen "?

Tags: meaning

There is a topic about *wenig* and *niedrig* but it is not clear for me.
As you know we could not use these words everywhere interchangeabely.
For example:

> Wenn sie ein geringes Einkommen haben, zahlen sie nur wenig Steuern.

Another example :

> Die Anzahl an Bällen ist zu gering.
> Ich habe zu wenige Bälle.

So I want to know a good explanation for them.

Comment: Which topic "is there"? this one? https://german.stackexchange.com/q/41452/36160 ? please insert your related topics. And please add which difference you understood until today / where you see equality. Right now I understand that your problem is: same object/context, (same) sentence - different word used -> why is it so?

Answer (score 5):

The words have a close semantic sense but their application differs

- **Wenig**. Indefinite pronoun, adverb.  Meaning *"not much"*, *"small"* or *"few in"* quantity.
- **Niedrig**. Adjective, adverb. Meaning *"falling short"* or *"low level"*, e.g: "The barrel had a low/short level of water".
- **Kaum**. An adverb, meaning *"barely"* (enough), literally: "Kaum genug".
- **Gering**. Can be an adverb, adjective, or noun. Meaning is very close to the above, but closer to "scarce".
- **Ein bisschen**. Indefinite pronoun, or adjective. Literally "a little bit".